# What kinds of structures support integration?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I am doing topology which neatly generalizes analysis,  which led me to wonder naturally about generalizations of calculus. Specifically I'm interested in knowing what is required of a mathematical structure to support integration. Wouldn't it be neat to observe integration and differentiation on rings (which  I suppose is impossible without more extensions), or other weird mathematical spaces.

Comment: I don't know diddly about them, but you should look into Lebesgue integration and measure theory.

Comment: In a locally compact group, one can define a natural measure called the [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure), and then carry out Lebesgue integration using that.

Comment: Riemannian manifolds have everything in multivariable calculus. The beginning notions culminate in Stokes Theorem.

Comment: Measure spaces which (as far as I know) include all of the above.

Comment: This is a tough and very deep question. I recommend Folland's Real Analysis to learn about (scalar-valued) measure theory and integration. A more advanced option is Dunford & Schwartz, which will teach you about vector-valued measure theory.

Comment: The nLab page on integration theory is an excellent reference, tying together integration theory from the analytic & cohomological perspectives. If you want a structural theory of integration, this is where to start: http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/integration+theory+-+contents